# variable within regex_findall in ansible

Tags: ansible

```
- name: Get names for all running Oracle databases from oratab file
  slurp:
    src: /etc/oratab
  register: oracle_patch_oratab

- name: Extract a list of DBs which mataches the Oracle Home
  set_fact:
    oracle_patch_dblist: "{{ oracle_patch_oratab['content'] | b64decode | regex_findall ('(.+v12201.+)', multiline=True, ignorecase=True) }}"
```

In regex_findall I have hard-coded a value as v12201 and I would like to replace that with variable. If so, what would be the syntax to be used within regex_findall? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  Add that, and show us some sample intput and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following method, it works fine.

```
- name: Get names for all running Oracle databases from oratab file
  slurp:
    src: /etc/oratab
  register: oracle_patch_oratab      

- name: "assign pattern"
  set_fact: 
    ora_ver: "12201"

- name: Extract a list of DBs which mataches the Oracle Home
  set_fact:
    oracle_patch_dblist: "{{ oracle_patch_oratab['content'] | b64decode | regex_findall ('(.+' + ora_ver | string + '.+)', multiline=True, ignorecase=True) }}"
```